# Minecraft will not run

Tags: java, minecraft

New minecraft and OS. Only has 3 user-installed applications.

```
  ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// But it works on my machine.

Time: 22/04/16 8:46 AM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:828)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcc.ap(SourceFile:594)
    at bcc.an(SourceFile:430)
    at bcc.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:828)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcc.ap(SourceFile:594)
    at bcc.an(SourceFile:430)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcc.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.9.2
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 4.4.0-21-generic
    Java Version: 1.8.0_77, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 156738408 bytes (149 MB) / 248774656 bytes (237 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.9.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: Could you add more details to your question (e.g Ubuntu version, graphic card in use)?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. What I needed to do was change the driver I was using to the X.org Nouveau driver. For anyone else experiencing this issue you can change that in "Additional Drivers"

For others:
I am using an Alienware M14x with nVidia GeForce GTX 765M.